# docker container not finding the unix socket

Tags: java, sockets, unix, docker

I have a docker container from which I want to spawn a new container. I am using com.spotify:docker-client:3.3.5 for communications. The output of `docker version` is shown below, as is the output from `docker images` and the echo to the docker unix socket.

The code I am running is

```
final DockerClient docker = DefaultDockerClient.builder()
        .uri(URI.create("unix:///var/run/docker.sock")).build();

String image = "docker.mydom.net/stock-availability:v1";
final ImageInfo imageInfo;

try {
    imageInfo = docker.inspectImage(image);
} catch (DockerException e) {
    return "(2) " + e.toString();
} catch (InterruptedException e){
        return "(3) " + e.toString();
}
```

what I see is a file not found error. It would appear that the problem is around the use of the unix socket, but I don't understand what is wrong. I don't want to open up a TCP port, the socket is restricted to just the docker group. Any help would be gratefully accepted!

```
2015-12-30 16:36:35.192  INFO 1 --- [sync-executor-0] o.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec   : I/O exception (java.io.IOException) caught when processing request to {}->unix://localhost:80: No such file or directory
2015-12-30 16:36:35.193  INFO 1 --- [sync-executor-0] o.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec   : Retrying request to {}->unix://localhost:80
2015-12-30 16:36:35.194  INFO 1 --- [sync-executor-0] o.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec   : I/O exception (java.io.IOException) caught when processing request to {}->unix://localhost:80: No such file or directory
2015-12-30 16:36:35.194  INFO 1 --- [sync-executor-0] o.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec   : Retrying request to {}->unix://localhost:80
2015-12-30 16:36:35.194  INFO 1 --- [sync-executor-0] o.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec   : I/O exception (java.io.IOException) caught when processing request to {}->unix://localhost:80: No such file or directory
2015-12-30 16:36:35.194  INFO 1 --- [sync-executor-0] o.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec   : Retrying request to {}->unix://localhost:80
com.spotify.docker.client.DockerException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory



0 ✓ docker@docker-002  ~/stock_availability $ docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.9.1
 API version:  1.21
 Go version:   go1.4.2
 Git commit:   a34a1d5
 Built:        Fri Nov 20 13:25:01 UTC 2015
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.9.1
 API version:  1.21
 Go version:   go1.4.2
 Git commit:   a34a1d5
 Built:        Fri Nov 20 13:25:01 UTC 2015
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

0 ✓ docker@docker-002  ~/stock_availability $ docker images
REPOSITORY                             TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
docker.mydom.net/login                v1                  2913b9ab6f65        59 minutes ago      489.4 MB
docker.mydom.net/stock-availability   v1                  626fb30c8d08        7 days ago          463.6 MB
docker.mydom.net/java                 jre-8               6675c4c07738        11 weeks ago        423.2 MB

130 ✗ docker@docker-002  ~/stock_availability $ echo -e "GET /images/docker.mydom.net/stock-availability:v1/json HTTP/1.0\r\n" | nc -U /var/run/docker.sock
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Server: Docker/1.9.1 (linux)
Date: Wed, 30 Dec 2015 16:45:06 GMT
Content-Length: 1738

{"Id":"626fb30c8d08..<snip>..400"}}}
0 ✓ docker@gb1-li-docker-002  ~/stock_availability $
```

Comment: "localhost:80 here is actually just the dummy host we use when using the Unix sockets stuff. This is because most HTTP-aware libraries (Apache, Jersey, etc.) expect there to be a host, even though that concept doesn't make sense for Unix sockets.

So that Opening connection {}->unix://localhost:80 always gets logged, even when things aren't working." https://github.com/spotify/docker-client/issues/146